# Ubuntu 20.0 after update WiFi/Ethernet not working

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, network-manager, ethernet

I am new to Ubuntu and did a update recently after which the WiFi and Ethernet is not working they are not shown in the network manager as well.
Here is the output of `sudo lshw -C network`

```
sudo lshw -C network
 
 *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Ethernet Controller
    product: AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
    version: 10
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm pciexpreess msi misx bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:c3300000-c333ffff ioport:2000(size=128)
 *-network UNCLAIMED
    description: Network Controller
    product: AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter
    vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
    physical id: 0
    bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
    version: 01
    width: 64 bits
    clock: 33MHz
    capabilities: pm pciexpreess msi misx bus_master cap_list
    configuration: latency=0
    resources: memory:c3200000-c327ffff memory:c3280000-c328ffff
 *-network:0
    description: Ethernet Interface
    physical id: 3
    logical name: virbr0
    serial: 52:54:00:5a:fd:8b
    capabilities: ethernet physical
    configuration: autonegotiation=off broadcast=yes driver=bridge driverversion2.3 firmware=N/A ip=192.168.122.1 link=no multicast=yes
*-network:1 DISABLED
    description: Ethernet Interface
    physical id: 4
    logical name: virbr0-nic
    size: 10Mbit/s
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of a terminal. It is text. Obviously the kernel was not properly upgraded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot with a previous kernel using grub menu and run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```

Then reboot.

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue.